# reversing an array of characters

Tags: string, reverse

```java
public class Reverse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char name[]="prakash".toCharArray();////initialisng array

        ////////swapping string order//////////////
        //////////i.e. reversing array of characters//////////

        for(int i=0;i<=(name.length)/2;i++)
        {
            int j=name.length-i;
            char temp;
            temp=name[i];
            name[i]=name[j];
            name[j]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: What does `name.length-i` equal on the first iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array indices are zero-based: the "first" element is at 0, the "last" element is at `length-1`.

Therefore, if you want `j` to go down from the last element, it should be

```
int j=name.length-1-i;
```

Comment: thanks a lot.....it works but it only works for string having odd no. of characters.....it shows wrong output for string having even no. of characters.....

Comment: Use `i<(name.length)/2` instead of `i<=(name.length)/2` to avoid swapping the middle pair of characters one extra time (if length is 4, our first character is 0th or 1st, that is, `i<2` not `i<=2`)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (name.Length-1) / 2; i++)
        {
            int j = (name.Length-1) - i;
            char temp;
            temp = name[i];
            name[i] = name[j];
            name[j] = temp;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you have

```
  int j=name.length-i;
```

you should have

```
  int j=name.length-i-1;
```

because the array is based at zero, and has no entry at position `name.length`.

Comment: thanks a lot.....it works but it only works for string having odd no. of characters.....it shows wrong output for string having even no. of characters.....